# Wordpress single page : using original images

Tags: wordpress, image-size

As a photographer i need my photos to be sharp. When i upload my photos on my Wordpress, they are resized in many different ways. I'd like to use the original one instead of a resized one, event if it takes a little bit longer.

As you can see on the link below, the image in the post is resized :

```
<img src="https://www.pixelkomando.com/cont/2017/08/ORIGINAL-1160x770.jpg" width="1160" height="770">
```

But i'd like :

```
<img src="https://www.pixelkomando.com/cont/2017/08/ORIGINAL.jpg"  width="1160" height="770">
```

Here's the link : https://www.pixelkomando.com/gare-de-durnal/

Thanks for your help!
VFero

Comment: What theme are you using? Many themes include code to specify which photo size to use, and may even generate custom sizes. Also I do not recommend stopping WP from generating multiple image sizes... even if you want to show the large photo, mobile devices should still use the smaller sizes - especially on 3G or 4G connection. Finally, please note that Stack Overflow is a site for programming questions, so your question is out of scope for the site: see [What can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do something like in [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-prevent-wordpress-from-generating-image-sizes/) article.

From the article:

> You can stop WordPress from generating default image sizes by visiting
>   **Settings » Media** in WordPress admin area. There you will see default
>   image sizes predefined by WordPress. You need to set these sizes to 0
>   which will prevent WordPress from generating default image sizes when
>   you upload a new image.

and also:

> Find the theme size code in your theme’s *functions.php* file. Simply
>   look for the code line containing [add_image_size()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) function. ... Removing these lines will stop your theme from generating those image sizes.

**Warning:**

But be aware that this will force everyone on a mobile to download the original version of the images. Thanks at @FluffyKitten for pointing this out in the comments.

Comment: I'm glad it works. I would appreciate if you accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Please note that this is bad practice, *especially* if you are uploading hi-res images. You should use appropriately sized images especially on mobile. Not doing so means that every photo - even as a thumbnail - must use the hi-res image. If you have a gallery, every one of the hi-res photos must be downloaded just to show the thumbnails. That's very slow, a waste of bandwidth and *highly* undesirable as a user. According to Google, one of the main reasons users abandon a site is speed, so you are just alienating potential clients and it will be unusable on 3G/4G connections.

Comment: Only BlockPost Images have been set on Hi-Res, all the other formats have a standard setting.

Comment: @Vfero, By disabling WPs default resizing, you are forcing everyone on a mobile to download the largest version of ALL images, instead of the ones that were resized - even the ones that have a standard setting. I don't know what you mean by "only blockpost images are hi-res", but it doesn't matter - *any* hi-res images are going to be an issue when they are embedded into a webpage, and especially on mobile, instead of just made available for download.

Comment: @FluffyKitten, I added your warning to my answer for future visitors to this question.

Comment: @user8230352 This solution might be suitable in some cases, e.g. if they can control the size of the uploaded images or have set up their own custom sizes, but I'd be worried that some people would use it without any thought so I'm glad you added the warning :-)